# Cocos2d-x Scene MenuItemLabel CC_CALLBACK_1 error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

OS : Win10
Language : c++
Cocos2d-x Ver : 3.8.1
Tool : Visual Studio 2013

```
//MainMenuScene.h

#ifndef ProjectV_MainMenuScene_h
#define ProjectV_MainMenuScene_h

#include "cocos2d.h"

class MainMenuScene :public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
{
public:

virtual bool init();

static cocos2d::CCScene *createScene();

CREATE_FUNC(MainMenuScene);

cocos2d::Label *PlayLabel;

void goPlayScene(cocos2d::Ref *pSender);
};


#endif

//MainMenuScene.cpp

#include "MainMenuScene.h"
#include "PlayScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

CCScene *MainMenuScene::createScene()
{
CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

MainMenuScene *layer = MainMenuScene::create();

scene->addChild(layer);

return scene;
}

bool MainMenuScene::init()
{
    if (!CCLayerColor::initWithColor(Color4B(255, 255, 255, 255)))
   {
    return false;
   }

PlayLabel = Label::createWithTTF("Play", "fonts/consola.ttf", 18);

PlayLabel->setColor(Color3B::BLACK);

auto PlayBtn = MenuItemLabel::create(
    PlayLabel,
    CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::goPlayScene, this));
```

// i thought CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::goPlayScene,this) mean call goPlayScene(Ref* pSender) when click or touch the label

```
PlayBtn->setPosition(Vec2(240, 100));

auto pMenu = Menu::create(PlayBtn, NULL);
pMenu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);

this->addChild(pMenu);

return true;
}

void MainMenuScene::goPlayScene(Ref* pSender)
{
CCScene *pScene = PlayScene::createScene();
TransitionScene *pTransScene = TransitionFade::create(1.0f, pScene, Color3B::WHITE);
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(pTransScene);
}
```

i don't know why function don't call when i clicked the label

Answer (score 0):

You is not passed an argument in the calling function

```
CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::goPlayScene, this)
```

You need either remove the `Ref* pSender` from `void MainMenuScene::goPlayScene()` or add an your sender in `CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::goPlayScene, this)` after `this`.

Comment: there's additional question. i don't know exactly what is "Ref *sender".May i ask you to show me some examples? it will be great pleasure

Comment: `Ref* sender` is a reference to object which call a given function. It is used when you use a handler function for a variety of buttons, and need to know which button was pressed.
I think in your case you should determine the method `void MainMenuScene::goPlayScene( )`

Comment: Example of using you can find [here](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/builder-sender-parameter-216003.html)

Comment: The best thank is an [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer)